# Multiple jsonSerialize Entity

Tags: php, symfony

I've been doing some research without any result. So I come here to ask directly the question.

I have an entity, in order to return it into some api call, I need to serialize it.

For now I have something like that

```
class Place implements \JsonSerializable{
    [...] fields lists [...]

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return array(
            "id" => $this->id,
            "title"  => $this->title);
   }
}
```

This is working right, but, i would like to be able to have multiple definition for the serialization because for the api1 I might want to return id and title, but may be for the api2 I would like to return id / title and resume.

Is there a way to make a condition into the jsonSerialize() ? Or some other way ? I'm pretty sure I already have done something like that in Java, that might be possible in php.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.7, you can use the serializer and serializer groups to provide different data. You can set it up via annotation.

- [Symfony serialization documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html)
- [Serialization groups block ticket](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups)

Otherwise, you can use JMSSerializerBundle, it contains alose groups and other useful features. [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)

Comment: I might be blind but I can't see where we say really what field are serialize in wich condition. Let's say I have installed JMS with composer. I guess this is the line `$serializer->serialize($data, $format);` but where the field serialized are specified ?

Comment: I added another link in my answer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks. Sad I haven't find the link by myself :(